# Detecting HTTP redirects

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests, http-redirect

I have a problem with a website called [www.webhallen.com](http://www.webhallen.com). I want to put any numbers and character after [www.webhallen.com/](http://www.webhallen.com/) for example [www.webhallen.com/3459gdfg](http://www.webhallen.com/3459gdfg). I then want to se if that website exist the problem is that the site rederect me to there own 404 page. How can I via requests see if they redirect me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting soft 404 redirects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814654/detecting-soft-404-redirects-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the response status code. If you get `response.status_code` as 404. You will have been redirected to there 404 site.